# Как получить хендл окна по PID процесса?

Tags: delphi, winapi, окно

Допустим, я нашел все процессы системы и получил их PID, юзая "`OpenProcess()`" с первым параметром "`PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` or `PROCESS_VM_READ or PROCESS_TERMINATE`".

Как теперь "пробраться вглубь", то есть добраться до окна? Например, обратное действие можно произвести с использованием "`GetWindowThreadProcessID()`".

Comment: GetWindowThreadProcessId возвращает ID потока, а не процесса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Впрямую это не сделать. Алгоритм следующий.

1. Пронумеровать все окна, используя EnumWindows.
2. Для каждого из окон выполнить GetWindowThreadProcessId.
3. Запомнить хэндл для искомого PID.

Comment: с чего вы взяли что PID меняется?